# how can I add nestead array of objects using convert-excel-to-json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, excel

I am trying to insert data from excel sheet using convert-excel-to-json npm. I am able to basic format of my data but i want to add also images as a nested array.

Here Is my code:

```
        app.post("/upload-excel", async (req, res) => {
            const newpath = __dirname + "/files/";
            const file = req.files.file;
            const filename = file.name;
            const worksheetsArray = xlsx.parse(filename); // parses a file

            const excelData = excelToJson({
                sourceFile: filename,
                sheets: [{
                    // Excel Sheet Name
                    name: worksheetsArray[0].name,

                    // Header Row -> be skipped and will not be present at our result object.
                    header: {
                        rows: 1
                    },

                    // Mapping columns to keys
                    columnToKey: {
                        A: '_id',
                        B: 'name',
                        C: 'address',
                        D: 'age',
                    }
                }]
            });
            console.log(excelData);
        });
```

The above code output is:

```
{
  Customers: [
    { _id: 1, name: 'Jack Smith', address: 'Massachusetts', age: 23 },
    { _id: 2, name: 'Adam Johnson', address: 'New York', age: 27 },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: 'Katherin Carter',
      address: 'Washington DC',
      age: 26
    },
    { _id: 4, name: 'Jack London', address: 'Nevada', age: 33 },
    { _id: 5, name: 'Jason Bourne', address: 'California', age: 36 }
  ]
}
```

The expected output is: Here i have added extra images

```
{
  Customers: [
    { _id: 1, name: 'Jack Smith',images:[{id:1, src:"sadasd.com"}], address: 'Massachusetts', age: 23 },
    { _id: 2, name: 'Adam Johnson', address: 'New York',images:[{id:1, src:"sadasd.com"}] age: 27 },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: 'Katherin Carter',
      address: 'Washington DC',
      age: 26,
images:[{id:1, src:"sadasd.com"}, {id:1, src:"sadasd.com"}],
 
    { _id: 4, name: 'Jack London', address: 'Nevada',images:[{id:1, src:"sadasd.com"}], {id:1, src:"sadasd.com"}], age: 33 },
    { _id: 5, name: 'Jason Bourne',images:[{id:1, src:"sadasd.com"}, address: 'California', age: 36 }
  ]
}
```